# What is the best way to debug CLR stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a fairly complex CLR stored procedure. What is the best way to debug the procedure? I would like to step through it if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is your friend. Or more info in your post.

[How to: Debug a SQL CLR Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165051.aspx)